# How to show additive group $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have no idea. Use if $x$ is exist for any $y$ and nature number $n$ that establishment $nx=y$ is divisible group?

Comment: Comment: This question shows that $\mathbb Q$ (with addition) is not cyclic. It it also true that $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Assume $f\colon \Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ is an isomorphism. Then we have $f(a)=1$ for some $a\in\Bbb Q$. For $b:=\frac12 a$, we then have $f(b)+f(b)=f(b+b)=f(a)=1$, which is impossible because $2x=1$ has no solution in $\Bbb Z$.